# Как правильно реализовать запросы из node.js к php api

Tags: node.js, api, rest, backend

Имеется сайт на котором изначально запросы от клиента приходят на сервер написанный на noodejs. А вся апишка, для получения данных, находится на другом сервере  написанном на php. Соответственно нужно постоянно слать из nodejs запросы к php api за данными. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли node.js какие нибудь встроенные методы для этого? Или может есть какие нибудь библиотеки?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такая библиотека: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request
Пример правильного запроса с ее использованием:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Думаю этот подойдёт. Но в таком случае мы фактически делаем ещё одни запрос к серверу. А если php сервер и node.js сервер, физически запущенны на одном физическом сервере(компе), есть ли какой нибудь способ более оптимально это сделать, может как то на прямую из одной программы обращаться в другую? Или ничего такого нету?

Comment: не-а. Общаться через localhost - вполне рабочая схема. Взаимодействие с БД точно также строиться.  Если не нравится - обращайтесь с клиента сразу к php-серверу, напрямую